# MediaPlayer creates new MediaPlayer instead of stopping

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have created a list adapter which is for a list of sounds. The user presses one and it plays the sound on a loop until they press to stop it. It shouldn't let more than one sound play at a time.

```
MediaPlayer mp;

public void playSound(int position){

    if(position!=-1){
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, ints.get(position));
            if(!mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();
            }else{
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }
```

This does the exact opposite of what I would like. It doesn't stop playing the sound and instead plays multiple instances of sounds at the same time.

Comment: You're creating a new instance of `MediaPlayer`, and then immediately checking if the new instance is playing, which it won't be. You need to check `mp.isPlaying()` before you call `MediaPlayer.create()`. You'll also need to make sure it's not `null` first.

Comment: Holy god, wow, thank you for pointing that out. Apparently my brain decided to give up.